# Can't get text to sit vertically middle

Tags: css

I can't get the text inside to sit vertically centered in the box. Right now, its sitting a bit too low.

https://jsfiddle.net/bye5vqpg/

```
.box {
position:relative;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #0b7;
display: inline-block;
height: 15px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
transition: 0.5s;
padding: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid #0b7;
-webkit-transition:0.5s;
}
```

Comment: `line-height: 100%;` ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's single row texts you should try `line-height` with fix height of a `div`

```
.box {
position:relative;
color: #0b7;
display: inline-block;
height: 40px; // changed
line-height: 40px; // changed
text-align: center;
transition: 0.5s;
padding: 5px; //removed
cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid #0b7;
-webkit-transition:0.5s;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bye5vqpg/2/)

EDIT:

If you still want to add `padding` to left and right then add

```
padding: 0 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `line-height` to be `15px`. This will work for single line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the "**height**" to auto and remove the "**line-height**" or change the "**height**" to equal with "**line-height**"

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline` to the box.

```
.box {
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #0b7;
    display: inline;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #0b7;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r5jt8uu0/